# What is the correlation between money notes and scale used in a song when singing?

Tags: scales, voice, composition, songwriting

I wonder what is the correlation between the scale I chose for a song and the "[money notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Money_note)" I'm going to sing in the more tense moments of the song, like in the prechorus. They are usually going to be notes on the higher side of the spectrum.

If I'm playing in A minor, is it more common for singers to choose B, D, E or G for the most tense, highest, "money" note, because these notes add to the suspense since they're not tonic notes? Or is that not the case and choosing a tonic there note is as common?

Comment: Had to check on the term 'money note'! I suspected that it isn't any particular note from a key/scale - it could be any. It's more the climax note, or highest note. Which, depending on who's singing, could be any note in any key/scale. In my opinion.

Comment: It's going to serve a different purpose in a bridge to a chorus. Bridge it's going to be a leading note, one that demands to resolve; chorus it's going to be a strong root/5th etc as a climax

Comment: Thanks for the answers, although they seem a bit contrary, haha. @Tetsujin, can you elaborate on "chorus it's going to be a strong root/5th" you mean at the end of a chorus, before going back to the verse?

Comment: Do you have access to any recordings with such money notes? Take a few of them and see what notes they are?

Comment: Yeah I did that some time ago and I will do it again, from what I remember the notes varied in terms of scale degrees the song was in.

Comment: There are a few problems here: 1. the term money note is not defined well. Most climatic vs highest are two very different contexts and if it's most climatic then is even further to interpretation unless strictly defined 2. Even if it was well defined, any of those notes could be at any scale degree or even a non scale degree depending on the actual material.

Comment: @Dom: I don't think that makes the answer opinion-based as much as it makes the answers dependent on circumstances.  It's more like "If you're using the note for A effect, you do B, but if you want a note that's more in a C context, you do D."  And in general, any note of the scale can work depending on context.  That's still a clear answer to the question, even if perhaps an unsatisfactory one.  (And I mean "unsatisfactory" in the sense that it doesn't help the person asking the question much.  Not that it should be an unsatisfactory answer according to the guidelines of this site.)

Comment: OP: try re-entering the question without mentioning "money notes". Call them climactic melody notes or something, just define what you mean. If you're able to clearly identify such notes and distinguish them from all other notes, it has to be a real thing, even if you don't know a term for it that won't cause an allergic reaction. Give a few examples of the notes, and don't assume that there has to be a relationship to _scale degrees_ as such. Maybe there's some other correlation, e.g. with chordal harmony at that point in the song. Scale degrees do different things depending on context.

Comment: @Athanasius it does make it broad though as someone else can give a different example in a different context and give a completely different explanation. The opinion based is the definition which make it so anyone can answer it an it will be equally valid yet different interpretation of the meaning of the term.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Good idea, should I post the question again then, or just try to edit this one?

Comment: @Dom I get what you're saying and your answer was good. I am aware it's a complicated and opinion based subject.

Comment: @SimplyTable in theory you should be able to edit the question and then get it re-opened. If you can provide details about the specific notes you found _and_ some harmonic context for each one, then others might be able to identify patterns that you can't see. But I can't promise that Dom lets the question live. ;) Anyway, as general advice I think you should consider other sounding notes and harmony, and what kind of a tension or surprise or something the "money note" creates in the actual combination of sounding notes. Don't simply look at scale degrees.

Comment: @piiperiReinstateMonica Thank you for this answer and all the help :)

Comment: You might be interested in a youtube channel called Holistic Songwriting.  He has an artist series where he analyses the styles of particular artists.  I remember his videos on Taylor Swift and The Weeknd both address note choice for the 'money notes' in particular (although he doesn't use that term).

Comment: @ibonyun Thank you so much, I will check it out! :)